# Using Python, some way to stop function calls in a queue when one of them returns something not 0?

Tags: python

Say I have function calls A to Z that accepts text and each function looks for something specifically and returns 0 if nothing, else a tuple. If a tuple is found, then stop the remaining function calls.

One way obviously is to do it with if statements, but I was wonder if there's something more efficient. Example of ugly if statement:

```
result = A(text)
if result is 0:
   result = B(text)
   if result is 0:
      ....
   else:
      break
else: 
  break
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is put all your functions into a list and execute them one by one until a non-zero result found, the code is like this:

```
def A(text):
    pass

def B(text):
    pass

def C(text):
    pass


text = ''

for func in (A, B, C):
    result = func(text)
    if result != 0:
        break
```

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, opinion-based, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.